# Where can I find a sniper rifle in Fallout New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I am almost 22 hours into game, at level 16. I'm playing with all DLC installed. I am in Camp McCarran right now. But I still haven't been able to find a single sniper rifle in the game. All I've found so far is a Hunting rifle and a scope to attach to it from a merchant.

So where can I find a sniper rifle that can take out death claws and mutants?

Is there any particular quest I have to complete to get a good sniper rifle?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fallout Wikia lists the following locations for the [sniper rifle](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Sniper_rifle_%28Fallout:_New_Vegas%29):

- 188 trading post - can be bought from the arms merchant after level 11. 
  Atomic Wrangler casino - one can be found on the top floor, first door of the Atomic
- Wrangler inside a very hard locked case.
- Caesar's Legion safehouse - one can be found in poor condition.
- Camp McCarran - can be bought from Daniel Contreras.
- Camp McCarran - on top of a bed in the First Recon tent, where Sterling is.
- Gomorrah - sometimes 3 in poor condition can be found in the room with gun shipments. Be sure you take them before you destroy the shipments with thermite during the quest How Little We Know.
- Gun Runners - can be bought from the Vendortron after level 11.
- Inside a (locked- hard) room in a ruined building, to the northeast of Mole rat ranch. Both of the doors are booby trapped into this building.
- One can occasionally be picked off a legionary assassin.
- Vault 34 - Two can be found in the Armory (Accessed by using the terminal in the Overseer's Office). They are in very poor condition.
- Two can be found on mercenaries outside of Jacobstown. 
  Hoover Dam - A few can be found on NCR troops at early levels. They are replaced by riot shotguns and marksman carbines later in the game.

There's also the [Gobi Campaign scout rifle](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Gobi_Campaign_scout_rifle), a unique variant of the sniper rifle:

- Sniper's nest - Found in the Very Hard-locked gun case that is next to an ammunition crate with .308 rounds. There is no key to open it if the lock breaks.

You may also wish to look into the sniper rifle's bigger brother, the [anti-materiel rifle](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Anti-materiel_rifle), or the unique [Christine's CoS silencer rifle](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Christine%27s_CoS_silencer_rifle) if you have Old World Blues. The [Ratslayer](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Ratslayer), found in Broc Flower Cave, also deserves a honorary mention for being an easily accessible, scoped gun that silently shoots 5.56mm rounds.

Comment: Thanks for the info I didn't knew there are 2 sniper in Camp Mccarran. I check it out today. Also do think level 16 is enough to start dlc?

Comment: @ElectricRouge depends on your playstyle, but it should be enough.

Comment: I mostly use guns. Mostly pistols and rifles and I have 70+ speech. I am playing on normal difficulty

Comment: @ElectricRouge In which case you might want to avoid Dead Money for a bit. It's a lot more difficult for a guns character than for a melee/unarmed character.

Comment: @Studoku Thanks for reply. What do you think is the best level to start dead money for me?

Answer (score 2):

You can find a Sniper Rifle in the tent where 1st Recon hangs out on a shelf inside of Camp McCarran, you can also find one in a building near New Vegas Medical Clinic (mind the mines and Grenade Trap at the front and back doors) behind a hard locked door on a shelf (there's also Magazines Purified Water, Chems and .308 rounds on other shelves)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a decent sniper, buy an anti-material rifle from the brotherhood of steel and then use a weapon repair kit on it. It does fairly good on Giant Rad Scorpions, don't know about death claws.

Comment: I can't stop laughing at 'brotherhood of steal' XD. Had to edit it or I can't even type this comment properly. But seriously, anti material does good damage on almost everything. The con is that the .50 bullets are hard to come by so I wouldn't even use it on rad scorpions. It also have very low fire rate, using it on a charging death claw and failing to hit will also make you regret not just using a shotgun instead.

Comment: Top that, while I do not remember exactly where, I am sure there are more places to get one other than buying from Torres

Answer (score -2):

The hunting rifle, although not the best, can indeed take down deathclaws and mutants... just be sure to have AP ammo.

Comment: The hunting rifle is not the sniper rifle though. And while the two may be used similarly, that's not what the OP is asking for